# How to do a file upload in react js which has multiple forms?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to submit a form using react-hook-form & react-step-builderin react js, I managed to submit the form with out file all other field are working except file.

How can I achieve this:

```
<input

          {...register("idproof", { required: true })}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          style={styles.file}
          type="file"
        />
      </div>
```

My code is also giving error when I tried to put it in codesandbox so i cant give a working example but i will put the link to codesandbox here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-worker-zicnr?file=/src/App.js

Please change the code in codesandbox so I can understand what is the working.